# Requesting Assistance In Getting My Head Around Facebook Login for Websites

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface, authentication

I'm wanting to implement the "Login With Facebook" that's common on websites but I'm having trouble grasping the whole concept and if anyone could assist me with this I'd be most appreciative.

I've been reading the documentation under this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ for days but I still don't "Get It".

Let's start with...

In the documentation, it says the JS SDK is easiest to use (for whom I dont know) but I'm thinking the NON JS version would be better and faster (and easier for me to grasp) but I don't know what to do. I'm "Stuck"

My main problem is I don't understand how I am suppossed to be able to insert an Auto Incrementing ID along with the person's first and last name into my DB. There's NOTHING or NOWHERE in the Facebook code where I could specify a DB, Table or Column so how is this data suppossed to get into my DB to log the user in??

I have a classifieds on my site of which I'm attempting to create a FB login for but as I said above, I'm stuck and could use help as I have only an intermediate level of knowledge regarding PHP and MySql

Comment: The JS SDK is indeed the simpliest way to log user in. You'd only have to add the sdk and write no more than 10 lines of code to log user in

Comment: Hi @Darvex Thanks so much for chiming in. I appreciate your response but I am at a loss as to what these 10 lines of code would contain. Could you please provide me an example?? I would like to learn how to do the whole thing in PHP because I know PHP and MySql much better than JS and AJAX but if you insist that JS SDK is the way to go, I'll just roll with that but I was also trying to keep my page load speed as low as possible

Comment: The reason JS SDK way is considered easier is because it includes less page reloads (with php, you'll have to redirect user to facebook link, then user returns with code back to your page, then you have to use the code to request access_token to finally access user's info). I'll post an example as soon as i can.

Comment: Wow... I kinda see what you mean by the JS is easier. Thanks so much for defining the reasoning. Take your time on the example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like discussed in comments, here's example using JS SDK

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery library, makes things easier. -->
        <title>FB example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK
            FB.init({
                appId      : YOUR_APP_ID,                        // App ID from the app dashboard
                status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
            });
// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    /*
        This function gets information about user and alrets user's name.
     */
    function getUserInfo() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php", //url to send ajax request to
            data: {
                json: response, // Key => value pairs of items to send
            },
            success: function(ajaxResponse) { // upon successful request
                alert(ajaxResponse); //Alert whatever response we got.
            }
        })
    })
}

    /*
        This function gets the login status of user
     */
    function getLoginStatus() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') { //User is connected to Facebook and authorized your app
                getUserInfo();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') { //User is connected to Facebook, but hasn't authorized your app
                login();
            } else { //User is not connected to Facebook
                login();
            }
        });
    }

    /*
        Function promts user to log in and asks for permissions
     */
    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                getUserInfo();
            } else {
                alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, {scope: 'email'}); // Comma separated permissions
    }

</script>

<a href="javascript:getLoginStatus()"/>Login</a>

</body>
</html>
```

This is very simple example. On the page you will see link "Login". Upon pressing it you'll be either asked to login (if you're not logged into Facebook, or you haven't authorized app yet), or it will show popup with your name. Most of the code has been taken from [JavaScript SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

**EDIT:**

To add user's data to your database, i would suggest making AJAX call from the `getUserInfo()` function. Replace alert part with ajax call to certain php file, which you will create and pass it the data from `response` variable (which contains data about user, like `response.name` and `response.email`). In the php file itself insert the information you got into database.

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

I've updated the code once again, namely i added jQuery library (easier for me to make ajax calls in it, although it's not much different from plain JS).

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And updated `getUserInfo()` function to make ajax request to `ajax.php`.

In `ajax.php` i've made only one line:

```
print_r($_REQUEST['json']);
```

This will simply print out whatever data was send via ajax, and you will see it in popup. Next step would be checking out what information you get, and take whatever you need (it's `$_REQUEST['json']` is simple array), and insert it into db.

Comment: Hi again Darvex and thanks for the example. I've actually seen this code in the FB documentation but I still don't see how or where I would insert the user's data into my DB

Comment: Is this where the code would go? // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

Comment: And what is an Event Listener?

Comment: Event Listener is object that can hook to certain events JS SDK provides, like the like button was clicked (if i recall correctly). But in most cases you wouldn't need it. As for inserting user's data, look at the edit

Comment: Hi Darvex, I'm still at a loss as to where to begin. I'd be glad to send you a 20 dollar bill via PayPal if you'd write the AJAX and code necessary to accomplish this

Comment: Just send me a PM (if possible on SO) whereas I can send you my email address and get your details to enable a PayPal donation to you.

Comment: @StuartKaufman I've updated my answer once again, with ajax request and some additional details, the only part left for you now is to add information to database. If you don't know how php works with mysql, google it, it's simple stuff.

Comment: I thank you for the extended response. This is going to take me some time to look over and comprehend well enough to put in practice.

Comment: Does " namely i added jQuery library " mean I need to download a Jquery library and install this on my server?? I just finished a ton of PHP and MySql tutorials and had planned on delving into JQuery soon, but from the basics outwards so I know nothing about JQuery.

Comment: I just had an Ah Ha moment... I believe this is a link to an external library? <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> Would it be wise to place this in an include's file so it's in the head of every page or will this slow things?

Comment: Yes, it's external library, and that line you copied includes it to your page. The library is relatively small, it won't slow down your page. Excessive use of heavy load scripts will though! But it's nothing you should worry about, when creating simple pages with close to trivial functionality, loading speed is rarely a concern.

Comment: Im still reading on all of this and will likely have additional questions but another HUGE thanks for the help you've provided!!

Comment: You are welcome. If you have more smaller questions, leave them here. If it's anything big, you should probably create new question here on SO.

Comment: @StuartKaufman since this is no longer related to original question i'd suggest to stop this comment wall and move to emails as you suggested. Leave your email here and i'll contact you asap.